# Why does set.contains method work for some objects only?

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, set

I'm trying to see how the **set.contains** method works. I made 4 different sets for array, list, set, and class type. But it doesn't work for array and class type.

```
class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<int[]> arraySet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<List<Integer>> listSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Set<Integer>> setSet = new HashSet<>();
        Set<Numbers> numSet = new HashSet<>();

        int[] array1 = {1,2,3};
        int[] array2 = {1,2,3};

        List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);
        List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

        Set<Integer> set1 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
        Set<Integer> set2 = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));

        Numbers num1 = new Numbers(1,2,3);
        Numbers num2 = new Numbers(1,2,3);

        arraySet.add(array1);
        listSet.add(list1);
        setSet.add(set1);
        numSet.add(num1);

        // false
        System.out.println(arraySet.contains(array2));
        // true
        System.out.println(listSet.contains(list2));
        // true
        System.out.println(setSet.contains(set2));
        // false
        System.out.println(numSet.contains(num2));
    }
}

class Numbers{
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;

    public Numbers(int num1, int num2, int num3){
        this.num1 = num1;
        this.num2 = num2;
        this.num3 = num3;
    }
}
```

What is the reason that **set.contains** works for Collection objects only?

Comment: Try giving System.out.println(arraySet);
        System.out.println(listSet);
        System.out.println(setSet);
        System.out.println(numSet); before  your sysouts . You will get to know the difference.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi Is it related to set.contains method?

Comment: It isnt directly related to the set.contains() method , but this is how you can deduce , where are you going wrong in your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `contains()` method is based on the `equals()` method, so the first will only work where the second has been overriden.

For example, arrays **do not override** the `equals()` method. So, an array reference `equals` another array reference **if and only if** both point to the same array object in memory (`array1 == array2`), so `contains()` doesn't work on them.

On the other hand, the `ArrayList` class **does override** the `equals()` method, such that two `ArrayList`s will be `equal` if both contain the same objects in the same order (also applicable **only** if the objects contained override the `equals()` method). So, `contains()` **does work** on them.

Comment: And you have to override `hashCode()` too, for it to work in the set.

Answer (score 0):

For HashSet that contains objects of a class that you wrote, you can override the equals() and hashCode() methods in the object class and the Hashset will consider two different objects as equal if they hold the same content.
You can generate the override methods automatically with the IDE.